# Deleting .snapshot directory contents

Tags: snapshot

I have a `signiant` agent that doesn't want to transfer files, then delete the contents, from a external storage because the `.snapshot` directory holds files.
`signiant` error is "File Exists".

The share that's being used is a dropfolder for a different application.

I would want to advise to delete the contents of this folder but I don't know what the impact would be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you cannot modify a snapshot at all - by definition it's a copy of a moment in time.

Perhaps you can redefine the Signiant base (home) directory to be one level below the one containing the `.snapshot` directory tree.

Comment: Thanks @roaima. 
This concerend transferring fles from external Qumolo storage.
The supplier advised what you wrote, also to exclude the .snapshot file in the signiant agent.
We couldn't change the share because of workflows on the client side. 
So, excluding the .snapshot folder provided the solution